# Meteor method doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, meteor

Assume that I have a `Collection` called `Tasks` which has few tasks in it.
I call a method to return a task array to the user but for some reason it doesn't return anything.

Here is a code for example:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
// This code only runs on the client
    Template.body.helpers({
       tasks: function () {
            // Show newest tasks first
            Meteor.call("getTasks", function(error, result) {
                return result; // Doesn't do anything..
            });
        }
    });
}

Meteor.methods({
    getTasks: function() {
        return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
});
```

Any ideas why when I call the method it doesn't return anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Meteor methods inside of a template helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Tasks.find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) returns a cursor, which makes no sense to transmit to the client via [DDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Data_Protocol).

You probably mean to return `Tasks.find().fetch()`, but that defeats the purpose of Meteor's very nice data synchronization mechanism.

Have you read [Understanding Meteor's publish/subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826804/understanding-meteor-publish-subscribe/21853298#21853298)?

Comment: But typing `return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});` instead of the method call works.

Comment: It works in the console because the autopublish package is added by default, which sets up a publication on server and a subscription on the client automatically. Seriously, read up on that "Understanding" answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I also read this and it really explained the system well! (and it's written by Sacha Greif too): https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/