# How to display result from Meteor.HTTP.Get

Tags: web-services, meteor, foursquare

**Edit**: Got it working now. The trick is to move the `HTTP.get` to the server-side and use the `simple:reactive-method` package to get result from a method.

I could use some help figuring out how to display the result of [Meteor.HTTP.Get](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call). The docs are sketchy and there's no topics here that relates to my case.

I'm [searching Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) to find local farmers & markets around you. then display the result in a map (no map yet). Here's the code:

The start page:

```html
<template name="locator">

    <a class="button" href="{{pathFor route='locatorMap' query='group=farmers'}}">Farmers</a>
    <a class="button" href="{{pathFor route='locatorMap' query='group=markets'}}">Markets</a>

</template>
```

The soon-to-be map page. **Edited: Mar 31, 2015**

```html
<template name="locatorMap">

    <div class="list">
        {{#each venues}}
            <p>{{name}}. {{location.lat}}, {{location.lng}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>

</template>
```

The routing (lib/router.js)

```js
Router.route('/locator', {name: 'locator'});
Router.route('/locator/map', {name: 'locatorMap'});
```

The helper (client/locator/locator.js). **Edited: Mar 31, 2015**

```js
// A static list of venue categories
Foursquare.categoryId = { ... };

Template.locatorMap.helpers({
    venues: function() {
        var search_group = Router.current().params.query.group;
        var search_categories = Foursquare.categoryId[search_group].join(',');
        var search_location = Geolocation.latLng();

        if (search_location) {
            // using simple:reactive-method
            return ReactiveMethod.call('FoursquareSearch', search_categories, search_location);
        } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error("No Location", "Failed to get ...");
        }
    }
});
```

The method (server/methods/foursquare.js). **Edited: Mar 31, 2015**

```js
Meteor.methods({
    FoursquareSearch: function(categories, location) {
        check(categories, String);
        check(location, Object);

        try {
            var search_result = HTTP.call(
                'GET', 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?',
                {
                    timeout: 5000,
                    params: { ... }
                }
            );
            return search_result.data.response.venues;
        } catch (_error) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("No Result", "Failed to fetch ...");
        }
    }
});
```

I can see data on the console. But i'm just not sure how how to pass it into a template helper. If you guys need more info, just let me know.

Any help is appreciated. Thx!

Comment: Convert `search` into a method and follow the advice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640400/get-meteor-method-return-value-inside-helper-function).

Comment: i've revised the method and helper. can you have a look again? the callback from Meteor.http.get now trows an undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is really just: "How do I call a method from a helper?", which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640400/get-meteor-method-return-value-inside-helper-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper). However, in order for those solutions to work, you'll need your method to return a value rather than making an asynchronous HTTP call (which returns `undefined`). The path of least resistance is to define your `FoursquareSearch` method only on the server (put it under the `/server` directory) and to use a synchronous method invocation. For example:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  FoursquareSearch: function(cat) {
    check(cat, String);

    var search_location = Geolocation.latLng();

    if (search_location) {
      try {
        // fill in the blanks here with params, timeout, etc.
        var result = HTTP.get(...);
        return result.data.response;
      } catch (_error) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("No Result", "Failed to fetch...");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: this works! thx! with a little note, i forgot that the Geolocation package don't work on the server side. so i have to move it to the helper.