# Meteor client call to server not returning data

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor, client, server

I am building an an application that has a `Cart`. The `Cart` has an attribute called `cartPrice` which gets updated when a user adds or removes items from the cart. I want the client to call a server method to return the updated value of `cartPrice` whenever the user adds/removes an item and the `cartPrice` changes. Here is my code:

`cart.js`:

```
Template.Cart.helpers({
   cartPrice: function() {
     return ReactiveMethod.call("returnCartPrice");
   }
});
```

`cart.html`:

```
<p>Cart Total: ${{cartPrice}}</p>
```

server side method to return cart price:

```
returnCartPrice: function(error, result) {
    var currUser = Meteor.user();
    var result = currUser.cartPrice.toFixed(2);
    return result;
}
```

The problem I have is the price on the client side will only update if I refresh the page.

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640400/get-meteor-method-return-value-inside-helper-function) for how to call a method from a helper. You need a reactive variable to change in order for your helper to run again. I'd need to know how the cart is stored in order to give a more precise answer (is it in a collection / session variable, etc).

Comment: Thanks David. I added the reactive-variable package and now the cart price is able to update. However, it will only update on the client side if i refresh the page... I updated my question to show the server side code as well as reactive-variable code...

Comment: Oh, so the only place the cart info is stored is on the user's document? If so, you don't even need a method for this.