# Meteor.call() callbacks not returning values to template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am having difficulty working with `Meteor.call` callbacks. I have defined a function which retrieves values from the server side; however, it does not return them to the template, in order to loop over them with an `{{#each}}` loop.

Here is the function:

```
search: function()  {
   Meteor.call('mySearchFunction', arg1, function(err, res) { 
     if (err) console.log(err); 
     else if(res) {
       console.log(res);  
       return res; 
     }
   }); 
 }
```

The `console.log(res)` shows me the data that I need, which is properly fetched with `mySearchFunction`, yet I am unable to pass it to the template handler, despite it being an array which may be iterated over. So I tried the following:

```
search: function()  {
   var s = Meteor.call('mySearchFunction', arg1, function(err, res) { 
     if (err) console.log(err); 
     else if(res) {
       console.log(res);  
       return res; 
     }
   }); 
   console.log(s); 
   return s; 
 }
```

And `console.log(res)` continues to display the requisite data, yet `console.log(s)` appears as `undefined`. I think this is because the async nature of meteor returns `s` before `res` gets a chance to be evaluated server-side. Either way, its strange that I cannot return data from a helper that I have stored in the helper function.

Answer (score 3):

On the client, `Meteor.call` is asynchronous - it returns `undefined` and its return value can only be accesses via a callback. Helpers, on the other hand, execute synchronously. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper) for how you can call methods from helpers. Here's a quick solution:

```
$ meteor add simple:reactive-method
```

```js
Template.showPost.helpers({
  search: function () {
    arg = Session.get('currentSearch');
    return ReactiveMethod.call('mySearchFunction', arg);
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what `arg1` is in your original post so I'm using a session variable in my solution, but that should get you on the right track.

The problem with this package is that it can encourage bad behavior, but it should be fine for method calls which don't change state (such as a search).

Also see the section about helpers in [this post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: arg1 is just a string, not sure if that makes a difference, I'm trying out your solution now...

Comment: I solved my issue with an answer from the question that you referenced. +1 for that.