# Return doesnt display from meteor helper when I use Meteor.call

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

Return value is getting printed in console. but it doesn't display in template

**my template**

```
<template name="Mytemplate">
<ul>
   {{#each Name}}
      <li>{{this}}</li> //No display
   {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

**js**

```
Template.Mytemplate.helpers({
  Name : function(){
    Meteor.call("getnNames", function(error, result) {
      if(error){
        alert("Oops!!! Something went wrong!");
        return;
      }else{
       console.log(result); // Got result in array ["john","smith"]
       return result;
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Am I right in return? or How to do it?

Comment: From this code, it should be working. There must be something else happening we can't see.

Comment: Point is, you cannot call a server method in a template helper. I mean you can, but won't get output on the template, which pretty much defeats the purpose. There are a couple workarounds. Have a look at [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper)

Comment: Never, ever, change your "application state" (such as set a Session or call a method) from a helper. A helper is a way to represent the current data state.

Answer (score 0):

A `Meteor.call` doesn't returning anything inside a template. Inside the `call` function, you return the results, but the call itself won't return anything.

From the [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call):

> On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method.

You can however, put the `result` in a `Session` variable and return that reactively.

Comment: I agree with the first part but disagree with the last part. The called meteor.method execution in the **client is a simulation**. It does mean that you should not take anything that goes away from it and change the "application state". It is "dangerous" somehow. Anyway, the question code is also incorrect because he is calling a method from a helper (which is something wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Because method calls are asynchronous there is no way to know when the return value will *actually* return. This means more often than not the helper will finish before your method call does. You have to understand that running Meteor.call on the client is non-blocking so your helper will just continue to execute and end before the return value ever comes back from the server. Probably you're approaching the problem the wrong way but as someone else has stated the best you can probably do is instead of returning from the helper, insert it into a reactive data source such as reactive var, the session or even a client-side  collection and then access this reactively from somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Method calls on the client are asynchronous and you cannot return value from asynchronous function. The solution is to use [reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) or [Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session):

```
Template.Mytemplate.helpers({
  Name: function() {    
    Meteor.call("getnNames", function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        alert("Oops!!! Something went wrong!");
      } else {
        console.log(result); // Got result in array ["john","smith"]
        Session.set('names', result);
      }
    });
    return Session.get('names');
  }
});
```

Comment: Never, ever, set a Session or call a method from a helper.

Comment: Just tell me why I should not use Session instead of ReactiveVar in a simple application...

Comment: I haven't said that. I said that you cannot **set** session (or call a method) inside a helper. The helper is just a way to represent the current data state of your application, if you change it (setting a session, for example) then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: In your code, everytime your helper is executed, you will call a method. And then the method will set a session. In that situation you might suffer a loop and, in the best case, you are calling the method more times than only once. The best way to achieve the same execution is moving the Meteor.call to the onCreated (for example). However, I still disagree with the way you have achieved the behaviour you want to get (anyway, it depends of what you want to do).