# #if with Roles.userIsInRole not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I am creating a modal to manage the permissions of a user. But when the modal is loaded. The console returns `true` from the server, if a users has the role. While `{{#if hasRole}`} is still showing the wrong label.

editUserPermissionsModal.html

```
<tbody>
    {{#each roles}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{this.name}}</td>
        <td>
            {{#if hasRole}}
            <span class="label label-success">Toegang</span> 
            {{else}}
            <span class="label label-danger">Geweigerd</span> 
            {{/if}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="roleSelect">
                {{#if hasRole}}
                <option value="allow">Toestaan</option>
                <option value="deny">Weigeren</option>
                {{else}}
                <option value="deny">Weigeren</option>
                <option value="allow">Toestaan</option>
                {{/if}}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

editUserPermissionsModal.js

```
Template.editUserPermissionsModal.helpers({
  roles: function() {
    return Roles.getAllRoles();
  },

  hasRole: function(){
    var userId = Session.get("editing_user");
    var role = this.name;
    Meteor.call("checkRole", userId, role, function(error, result){
      if(error){
        console.log("error", error);
      }
      if(result){
        console.log(result);
        return result;


      }
    });
  }

});

Template.editUserPermissionsModal.events({
  "change .roleSelect": function(event, template){

    var addRole = event.target.value;

    if(addRole == 'allow') {
      var user = Session.get("editing_user");
      var role = this.name;

      Meteor.call('addRoleToUser', user, role)

    }

  }
});
```

server.js

```
checkRole:function(userId, role) {
    return Roles.userIsInRole(userId, role);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical "method call within a helper" issue. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper).

Given that you need variable arguments to your method, the easiest solution in your case would probably be using [David Weldon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357254/1439597) and install Sashko's [meteor-reactive-method](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method) package:

```
$ meteor add simple:reactive-method
```

And then:

```
Template.editUserPermissionsModal.helpers({
  roles: function() {
    return Roles.getAllRoles();
  },

  hasRole: function(){
    var userId = Session.get("editing_user");
    var role = this.name;
    var result = ReactiveMethod.call("checkRole", userId, role);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
});
```