# How Do I Pass Input Values to Helper Functions in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I'm building an order form that extracts data from ebay listings. It has a section where you add line items, and you use a button to add another item. It adds in another instance of a template (iterated through with a lineItems helper) This works fine.

So, within that template I need it to search using the eBay api (I already have a Meteor method set up to do this which I do not want to include bc it has sensitive information). You enter the id of the eBay listing into an input, and it automatically fills in the information for the line item like the title of the listing.

So how can I pass the parameter (the listing ID that I want to get from the input value) through my getEbayItemTitle helper?

Here's my helper function:

```
 getEbayItemTitle: function (id) {

    Meteor.call('getEbayItemData', id, function(error, result) {
       Session.set('ebayFetch', JSON.parse(result.content));
    });
    var item = Session.get('ebayFetch');

    return item.Item.Title;
 }
```

And in my template:
(I placed **LISTING ID** in place of where I have an actual listing ID)

```
 {{#each LineItems}}
    <!--some HTML -->
    <input type="text" class="order-ebay-id" placeholder="Ebay Id">
    <!--some HTML -->
    {{getEbayItemTitle 'LISTING ID'}}
    <!-- some HTML -->
 {{/each}}
```

I previously achieved this by coding it an entirely different way...I appended each line item on with jQuery as a div. But issue was, you would need to enter in the ebay listing id twice in order for the title to finally show up.
So I figured I needed to use templates and helper functions so the data is reactive.

I really hope this makes sense.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but I'd strongly recommend reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper).

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks! I am using the answer I accepted but that information is very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `Meteor.call()` that itself calls an outside API in a helper can be expensive. Put a `console.log()` in your helper to see how often it's running! But back to your question, your approach of passing *listingId* as a parameter to your helper is correct if you know the *listingID* beforehand. However since it's a user input you need to instead extract it from the DOM in your helper.

```
 getEbayItemTitle: function(){
   var title = "";
   var listingId = $('.order-ebay-id').val();  // get value from input field
   if ( listingId.length() > 0 ){
     console.log('Meteor.call with listingId '+listingId);
     Meteor.call('getEbayItemData', listingId, function(error, result) {
       Session.set('ebayFetch', JSON.parse(result.content));
     });
     title = Session.get('ebayFetch').Item.Title;
   }
 return title;
 }
```

A better approach than a helper would be to tie an event to the input field.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'blur .order-ebay-id': function(ev){
    var listingId = $('.order-ebay-id').val();  // get value from input field
    if ( listingId.length() > 0 ){
      Meteor.call('getEbayItemData', listingId, function(error, result) {
        Session.set('ebayFetch', JSON.parse(result.content));
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Then just have the helper return the session variable:

```
 getEbayItemTitle: function(){
   var title = "";
   if ( Session.get('ebayFetch') ) title = Session.get('ebayFetch').Item.Title;
   }
 return title;
 }
```

Comment: I don't know why but for some reason I was trying to call my method everywhere but in an event! Thank you! :)

Comment: As a random side question...I usually use on change for my input events. Is there any reason I should use blur instead?

Comment: *On change* will cause the method to be called after every character is typed. *On blur* will be after they leave the field. For an eBay auction id a partial search doesn't make sense.