# Set geolocation in a global helper (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, geolocation, google-geocoder

i try to set so geolocation informations in an helper. I use these packages:

`mdg:geolocation`,
`aldeed:geocoder`

This is my helper:

```
Template.registerHelper("geo", function () {
  var geo = Geolocation.latLng() || { lat: 0, lng: 0 };

  if(geo.lat !== 0){
    var infos = Meteor.call('locationName', geo.lat, geo.lng, function(err, res){
        return res[0];
    });
  }
});
```

This is the object returned

[image]

And this is my server call

```
Meteor.methods({
  locationName: function(lat, lng){
  console.log(lat, lng);
  var geo = new GeoCoder({
    geocoderProvider: configs.geocoder.geocoderProvider,
    httpAdapter: configs.geocoder.httpAdapter,
    apiKey: configs.geocoder.apiKey
  });

  var reverseGeocoding = geo.reverse(lat, lng);

  return reverseGeocoding;
}
});
```

I tried a lot of thing but my {{geo.city}} is always empty. How can i structure it correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you use `res[0]`? Try to use `res.city`...

Comment: I think OP implies that `res[0]` contains the object which has the `city` property.

Comment: You're right BraveKenny

Answer (score 0):

You are in a typical issue of [method call within a helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper). Look at your template helper's code. It basically does this:

```
Template.registerHelper("geo", function () {
  // inside helper
  // doing some stuff...
  Meteor.call('someMethod', function(err, res){
    // Other scope!
    console.log("Toto, I've a feeling we're not in the `geo` helper any more.");
    return res; // returning this to nowhere
  });
  // back inside helper
  return undefined; // returns before the above callback even triggers
});
```

The issue is that you cannot return something from a method call's callback and expect the helper from which you called that method to return this value: they're different scopes, because method calls are asynchronous. Here is what you can do:

```
Template.registerHelper("geo", function () {
  return Session.get('locationName');
});

updateLocationName = function (geo) {
  return Meteor.call('locationName', geo.lat, geo.lng, function(err, res){
        Session.set('locationName', res[0]);
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var geo = Geolocation.latLng() || { lat: 0, lng: 0 };
    Session.setDefault('locationName', null);
    if(geo.lat !== 0){
      var infos = updateLocationName(geo);
    }
  });
}
```

If you want to update your session variable (inside an `onRendered` or `autorun` for example), you will just have to call `updateLocationName()` with an updated `Geolocation.latLng()` object.

Comment: It doesn't work. Thank you for your answer about the scope, i tried a lot of things... In Meteor.startup, the geo variable is set to { lat: 0, lng: 0 }. I need to set it at first load.

Answer (score 0):

I made it worked, but maybe it have a better way to do it. Thank you for your answer! There's my code

```
Template.registerHelper("geo", function () {

if(Session.get('geolocation') === null){
    var geo = Geolocation.latLng() || { lat: 0, lng: 0 };

    if(geo.lat !== 0){
        Meteor.call('locationInfos', geo.lat, geo.lng, function(err, res){
            Session.set('geolocation', res[0]);
        });
    }
}

return Session.get('geolocation');

});
```

I set the session variable at NULL in Meteor.startup.