# Why is the template not updating in real time?

Tags: javascript, meteor, real-time

I have this Meteor code which is **meant** to update a notifications' template in real time **whenever** an appropriate action is triggered:

~/server/app.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    notifs: function(){
        return Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId}, {'profile.notifs': 1});
    }
});
```

and:

~/client/apps.js

```
Template.notifs.helpers({
  notifs: function(){
    Meteor.call('notifs', function(err, data){
      Session.set('notifs', data);
    });
    return Session.get('notifs');
  }
});
```

finally:

~/public/templates/notifs.html

```
<template name='notifs'>
    {{#each notifs}}
        <p>...</p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

What this code **does** for the moment is just listing the notifications when the user logs in, **but** fails to update in real time to show new notifications as actions are triggered. 
New notifications show up only after a page refresh (which is, honestly, useless).

After hours of googling I give up and post this here so someone can help me, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Meteor.methods `return Moteor.users...` Moteor?

Comment: @Ahmed A meteor `call` isn't reactive - it's just a remote procedure call. You need to publish the users you are interested in, and then `find` them in your helper.

Comment: Sorry for the typos, it's 2 am in here, so ... I'll get them fixed right away!

Comment: @DavidWeldon: Oh, I see! Well, I already published the users, so now all I need to do is to `find` them. I'll try that out and hope it works. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidWeldon: That was it! Thank you so much! Please post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: New notifications collections. With server methods. http://meteorpad.com/pad/CmDdFH7nJm3om7cfS/Notifications - be sure that Meteor.userId() doesn't return undefined.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At it's core, this question is about [reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity). Because `Meteor.call` isn't a reactive data source (it's just a remote procedure call), the helper won't run again if the underlying data changes.

Because the necessary user document is already published (it's for the current user), the method call isn't needed. You could rewrite your helper using [find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) (a reactive data source) like this:

```
Template.notifs.helpers({
  notifs: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
  }
});
```

However, [Meteor.user()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user) gives you the same functionality:

```
Template.notifs.helpers({
  notifs: function() {
    return Meteor.user();
  }
});
```

However, you don't really even need this because templates come with the [{{currentUser}}](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentuser) helper. So you can drop the helper altogether and modify your template like this:

```
<template name='notifs'>
  {{#each currentUser.notifs}}
    <p>...</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

If you ever actually do need the result of a meteor call in a helper, you should read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the additional valuable information!