# Meteor running a Method asynchronously, using meteorhacks:npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, steam

I'm trying to use the Steam Community (`steamcommunity`) npm package along with `meteorhacks:npm` Meteor package to retreive a user's inventory.  My code is as follows:

lib/methods.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getSteamInventory: function(steamId) {
    // Check arguments for validity
    check(steamId, String);

    // Require Steam Community module
    var SteamCommunity = Meteor.npmRequire('steamcommunity');
    var community = new SteamCommunity();

    // Get the inventory (730 = CSGO App ID, 2 = Valve Inventory Context)
    var inventory = Async.runSync(function(done) {
      community.getUserInventory(steamId, 730, 2, true, function(error, inventory, currency) {
        done(error, inventory);
      });
    });

    if (inventory.error) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('steam-error', inventory.error);
    } else {
      return inventory.results;
    }
  }
});
```

client/views/inventory.js:

```
Template.Trade.helpers({
  inventory: function() {
    if (Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      var inventory;
      Meteor.call('getSteamInventory', Meteor.user().services.steam.id, function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
          inventory = result;
        }
      });

      return inventory;
    }
  }
});
```

When trying to access the results of the call, nothing is displayed on the client or through the console.

I can add `console.log(inventory)` inside the callback of the `community.getUserInventory` function and receive the results on the server.

Relevant docs:

- https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm
- https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steamcommunity/wiki/CSteamUser#getinventoryappid-contextid-tradableonly-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a reactive data source inside your `inventory` helper. Otherwise, Meteor doesn't know when to rerun it. You could create a `ReactiveVar` in the template:

```
Template.Trade.onCreated(function() {
  this.inventory = new ReactiveVar;
});
```

In the helper, you establish a reactive dependency by getting its value:

```
Template.Trade.helpers({
  inventory() {
    return Template.instance().inventory.get();
  }
});
```

Setting the value happens in the `Meteor.call` callback. You shouldn't call the method inside the helper, by the way. See [David Weldon's blog post on common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) for details (section *Overworked Helpers*).

```
Meteor.call('getSteamInventory', …, function(error, result) {
  if (! error) {
    // Set the `template` variable in the closure of this handler function.
    template.inventory.set(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: I've done this, and opted to perform the ```Meteor.call``` in the ```onCreated``` callback, however I'm still not getting anything on the client.  I have followed the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper), as suggested in David Weldon's post.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is you're calling an async function inside your **getSteamInventory** Meteor method, and thus it will always try to return the result before you actually have the result from the **community.getUserInventory** call. Luckily, Meteor has [WrapAsync](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) for this case, so your method then simply becomes:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getSteamInventory: function(steamId) {
    // Check arguments for validity
    check(steamId, String);

    var community = new SteamCommunity();
    var loadInventorySync = Meteor.wrapAsync(community.getUserInventory, community);

    //pass in variables to getUserInventory
    return loadInventorySync(steamId,730,2, false);
  }
});
```

**Note:** I moved the `SteamCommunity = Npm.require('SteamCommunity')` to a global var, so that I wouldn't have to declare it every method call.

You can then just call this method on the client as you have already done in the way chris has outlined.

Comment: That small ```Meteor.wrapAsync``` over ```meteorhacks:npm```'s version of the function makes all the difference, coupled with the rest of @chrisklaussner 's answer :)