# helpers result not passed to template in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a small helper which calculates an average by calling my method on the server side.

```
Template.replyDoc.helpers({
    averageVote : function(userId){
        var question = Template.parentData();
        Meteor.call("averageVote",question._id,userId,function(error,result){
            console.log('average: ' + result);
            return result;
        });
    }
});
```

then I am trying to render my helpers results in my template:

```
<template name="replyDoc">
    <div class="list-group-item">
        AVERAGE:{{averageVote userID}}
    </div>
</template>
```

average value is calculated properly as console.log works fine but i cannot see it rendered. Why is it the case and how I should solve it please?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer;[meteor methods inside helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper)

I used simple reactive-method and it worked.