# Meteorjs - Meteor.call('myMethod') returns three objects and not one array?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a client that have this helper:

```
Template.eventTemplate.helpers({
    returnUsersEvents: function(){
        Meteor.call("events.getByUserId", function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log("error" + error.reason);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
        return result; 
        });

    }
});
```

The method on collection

```
Meteor.methods({
  'events.insert'(Event) {
    Events.insert(Event);
  },
  'events.getByUserId'(){
    var events =  Events.find({UserId: Meteor.userId()}).fetch();
    console.log(events);
    return events;
  }
})
```

I have one object in my collection. But I retrieve three objects of the same type. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my template

```
<ul class="demo-list-item mdl-list">
    {{#each returnUsersEvents}}
    <li class="mdl-list__item">
        <span class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
            <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">map</i>
            <a class="" href="/event/{{_id}}">{{EventName}}</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Because of fetch()

Comment: I did try to remove fetch, but then nothing returns at all. Not even error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your `returnUsersEvents()` helper is not returning anything at all. You have a return statement **inside the callback** of the Meteor.call(). This will **not** become the return value of the `.call()` itself.

`Meteor.call()` is asynchronous, which means that the `.call()` will return before the result is available inside the callback. To make this work, you  need the helper to return the result from the callback **when it arrives**, which is at some point in time after the helper has returned the first time.

The typical pattern in Meteor to achieve this is to use a [ReactiveVar](http://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) that the helper is tracking on, and to set that ReactiveVar from inside the callback.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147813/how-to-use-meteor-methods-inside-of-a-template-helper) is a SO answer which shows how to do that.

And on the server: You need the fetch. Otherwise you are returning a database cursor, which is not a serializeable object (which means it can't be returned over DDP, the protocol that the Meteor server sends the result to the client over)